# Is this hadith about hanging the whip authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

Assalamualaikum, is the Hadith below authentic? :

> "Hang your whip where your wife can see it." (Hadith Musannaf, Abdul Razzaq)

Comment: Do you have the original text and wording (in Arabic) at hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest wording I could find in Musannaf Abd al-Razzaq is:

> علقوا السوط حيث يراها أهل البيت
>
> Hang your whip where it can be seen by the members of your household
>
> <sup>— [مصنف عبد الرزاق](https://shamela.ws/book/13174/19428#p1)</sup>

There is dispute concerning its authenticy, some considered at least one of its chains to be Hasan while others consider them all to be Da'if. Refer to [Islamweb](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/210097/islam-did-not-command-detaining-a-sinful-wife-in-a-separate-room):

> As for the second Hadeeth which is the saying of the Prophet, sallallaahu ‘alayhi wa sallam: “Hang your whip where the members of your household can see it.” [At-Tabaraani in Al-Mu‘jam], some scholars deemed it weak while some others deemed it Hasan [good].

Also see for example number [431 in الأحاديث المشتهرة الضعيفة](https://archive.org/details/rain_bow2020_yahoo_20171227/page/n337) and number [1446 and 1447 in سلسلة الصحيحة](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/2119#p10).